# VBA - Como autocompletar uma palavra no meio da TextBox

Tags: vba, autocompletar

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em VBA cuja a principal entrada é uma função f(x,y). Sigo encontrando grande dificuldade em configurar a TextBox para limitar as entradas, como por exemplo: ao inserir o caractere "c", eu gostaria que aparecesse "cos" para evitar erros de entrada. Entretanto, não estou conseguindo pensar em uma solução que consiga 'autocompletar' em qualquer lugar do texto.

Outro problema que também não consegui pensar em uma solução seria se o usuário resolvesse apagar algum caractere dessa palavra única, ex. "cs". Nesse caso, gostaria que toda a palavra "cos" fosse apagada, ou melhor, que "cos" fosse uma coisa só.

```
Private Sub ctx_funcao_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
Dim MyStr As String
Dim pos As Integer

Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 8 '//Backspace (seta de apagar)
        Case 99 '//c
        Case 108 '//l
        Case 115 '//s
        Case 116 '//t
        Case 40 To 57 '//Números de 0 a 9 e operadores matemáticos
        Case 94 ' ^
        Case 120 To 121 ' x e y
         
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0 '//Não deixa nenhuma outra caractere ser escrito
    End Select

End Sub
```

Até o momento eu tenho só isso de configurações. Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Oi, h2ocampioni!

Validação de entrada é sempre um problema, eu não gosto muito de travar ou verificar após cada caractere porque é necessário pensar em todas as situações possíveis.

É mais elegante verificar no lostfocus (quando se aperta tab ou sai do campo), algo muito comum na digitação do CPF e CNPJ onde tem um DV para responder se o número está certo ou errado.

Sugeri a resolução para dois problemas que você relatou, identificar padrões corrompidos, e autocompletar assim que aparecer uma letra que você espera.

Como é claro que você tem um padrão definido que não está completamente exposto na pergunta, você pode partir com os ajustes à partir daí

```
 Dim MyStr As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    
    Select Case KeyAscii
            Case 8 '//Backspace (seta de apagar)
            Case 99 '//c
               KeyAscii = 0
               TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "cos"
             
            Case 108 '//l
            Case 115 '//s
            Case 116 '//t
            Case 40 To 57 '//Números de 0 a 9 e operadores matemáticos
            Case 94 ' ^
            Case 120 To 121 ' x e y
             
            Case Else
                KeyAscii = 0 '//Não deixa nenhuma outra caractere ser escrito
        End Select
    
      If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, "cs", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
         TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "cs", "cos")
      End If
```